# Cmake missing DLLs

Tags: c++, dll, cmake

I'm trying to use Cmake but when I start I'm getting missing DLL: libgmp-10.dll

Now I know that usually appears because of wrong/missing environmental variables, but that's impossible, I have both Mingw path, as well as mingw/bin, besides I've worked with mingw for over a year, if it was missing I would have had problems with it.

What is causing this & how can I fix it?

Comment: CMake doesn't depend upon [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), the project you are building does and that needs configuring to point to its location.

Comment: Since it's my first time using Cmake I have no idea how to do that, but it doesn't say that just for the project, it says that no matter what I try to do (I also tried building a library with it, and another project besides the main one which was almost empty)

Comment: Ok, so some crazy library mess.  Are you building CMake yourself or trying to use a Cygwin, Mingw, Mingw 64-bit fork, or native package?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try pre-build version from [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html).

Another way to solve your issue is to find missed dll and put it with binary you've built.